# Roslyn - Find out if called method calls method

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to learn how to use Roslyn and I keep hitting roadblocks that take a lot of thought to figure out how to get around. At the moment, focusing on experimenting to understand what's possible.

```
void Method1(){}
void Method2()
{
    Method1();
}
void Method3()
{
    Method2();
}
```

If I want to check if Method2 calls Method1, It's easy because I just look at it's syntax tree. As I understand it, If I'm looking at Method3 though and I want to find Method2, I should use the semantic tree because Method2 may be in a different file/namespace/etc.

My question is if I have only the IMethodSymbol of Method2, is there any way to find out if Method2 calls Method1?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you know how to get from `MethodDeclarationSyntax` for `Method3` to `IMethodSymbol` for `Method2` and from `MethodDeclarationSyntax` for `Method2` to `Method1`, but you don't know how to get from `IMethodSymbol` for `Method2` to `MethodDeclarationSyntax` to `Method2`.

To do that, you can use [`DeclaringSyntaxReferences`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.isymbol.declaringsyntaxreferences):

```
var method2Syntax = symbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.Single().GetSyntax();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Broken link, and this answer could be improved. I personally don't know how to get those things, and I find it hard to follow the above paragraph :D